# More efficient way to grab MySQL row populated with single value

Tags: php, mysql

Right now I'm trying to set a variable from an SQL response without doing it more than necessary.

The situation is I have a SQL result from a SELECT + JOIN query with a `user_id` column that has only a single value. The other columns are different per row and I need to loop through them for that data. I was wondering if there was a way to extract the homogeneous value from the `user_id` column without setting it over and over again to a variable in my while loop.

Code:

```
#where I would like the $user_id to be set
while($responseArray = $response->fetch_assoc()){
    $userId = $responseArray["user_id"]; #what I don't want to do
    #other fetching stuff
}
```

SQL:

```
SELECT users.username, users.user_id, posts.post_id, posts.post_content, posts.number_comments, comments.comment_id, comments.comment_post_id 
FROM users 
JOIN posts 
JOIN comments 
WHERE delete_bit = 0 AND username = "john";
```

Comment: Maybe show us your SQL... but I have a feeling you should be able to use a WHERE clause.

Comment: SELECT users.username, users.user_id, posts.post_id, posts.post_content, posts.number_comments, comments.comment_id, comments.comment_post_id FROM users JOIN posts JOIN comments WHERE delete_bit = 0 AND username = "john";

Comment: A) Does this work? I am fairly certain that `JOIN` needs an `ON` with it. B) Where/What is `posterId`

Comment: Oof. A lot of mistakes on this one. Sorry about that.

Comment: A) Based off what I saw online, I don't think it does? I might be wrong. B) I think I had some code mixed up.

Comment: I just tested the code with ON and I get the same result. The results I believe are correct. I think my discussion with Marc is probably enough from here for me.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get away from fetching at least one result row. Even the `fetchOne()`-type functions do this. But if you only want a single row, why even bother using a loop in the first place?

```
$result = $db->query(...);
$row = $result->fetchRow();
$value = $row['somefield'];
```

would be far better than something silly like

```
$result = $db->query(...);
while($row = $result->fetchRow()) {
    $value = $row['somefield'];
    break;
}
```

Comment: Oh. I typed it wrong. There's a column with all the same value. My bad.

Comment: you can't set the value outside the loop - you **HAVE** to fetch a row to get any data out of the query. if you fetch a row outside the loop just to get posterID, you'll also fetch all the OTHER fields in the result set for that row as well,w hich means you've now got one less row for the while() loop to deal with. don't worry if the posterID is the same in all rows. the microscopically minuscule overhead of setting the same value over and over is nothing to worry about it.

Comment: Ok. I was just worried that it was stylistically a bad choice. In my brain it kind of felt like a "hack" to just keep setting it each iteration.

Comment: no, it's not really a hack. but if the value doesn't change over the query set, then technically it could be regarded as a primary key for that result set e.g. `select foo, bar from baz where foo=$val` - you don't need to fetch `foo` in the first place, because you already have the only value it could ever be in `$val`.

Comment: mmm... It's kind of like that. In more detailed in terms of my situation, each user has a username and user_id. The user_ids are the primary key in my database. When I do my query, I'm trying to grab the user_id with the username and everything else in one query to reduce overhead. I unfortunately have to just add that primary-key-like value to my response.